# C++ sprintf boxing... how?

Tags: c++, printf

I want to make my own string formatting function in C++ and I'd like to have the function figure out how big types are on it's own without specifying it, like sprintf.  Does it work by cheating or is it something I can do as well?

Comment: In what way does sprintf figure out how big anything is? And what does this have to do with boxing?

Comment: "I want to make my own string formatting function in C++"? For why? Have you considered using streams instead?

Comment: in sprintf you just specify like 'u' for an integer and it figures out how big it is...  you can do any size.  I'm developing on a compiler that doesn't implement C++ 11 so that isn't really an option

Comment: It doesn't figure out how big anything is; it's programmed to *know* that `%u` represents `unsigned`, and the compiler knows what `sizeof(unsigned)` is.

Comment: Ryan, that way lies madness. Do you _really_ want to give up type safety in your I/O?

Comment: Well unsigned integers can be 8, 16, 32 or 64 bits...

Comment: Lol I just want to write a replacement for sprintf that I can use in a string class, C++ doesn't support real boxing so type safety isn't really an option

Comment: Ryan, for a given implementation, it's only _one_ of those, hence the implementation knows. Woe betide anyone who uses a 32-bit format specifier with a 64-bit value on the stack with `printf`. That's why you should avoid this and use the c++ standard stuff like `cout << blah blah`.

Comment: Yes, but `unsigned` has exactly one size during any given compilation. If you pass in a different-sized variable, you need to say so with a size modifier, like `%lu`. Which part of your *real* task are you having trouble with? Ask a question about *that*, please.

Comment: sprintf works with any size unsigned though.  So when you call it you're saying it's an unsigned value but not specifying the size.  When you use va_start to pull the data off the stack, you have to specify a size.  The compiler has to send the size info as another parameter so sprintf can work...

Comment: The compiler doesn't have to specify a size. We know it doesn't have to because it doesn't specify a size. Sprintf works the same in C as it does in C++. Sprintf knows the size to pass to va_start because it has already parsed the `%` format from the input string, and it knows which size goes with which combination of letters, and therefore how many bytes to read from the argument list.

Comment: Ryan, the version of `sprintf` in C++ is the exact same as it is in C.  You are right that unsigned integers can be 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, but `"%u"` means `unsigned int`. There's nothing magical going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

Output of objects to strings should probably be done with the regular `stringstream` stuff, so that you can use all the wonderful features that exist in c++ *without* redeveloping the wheel.

Quite a lot of time has been spent getting that working well, I'm not sure about the rationale of repeating that effort. Perhaps if you told us the *real* requirement for bypassing what's already there (and "I just want to do it myself" is rarely a good reason), we could come up with more targeted or applicable answers.

Comment: @Ryan also take a look at Boost Format, which lets you do printf-style formating while using streams.

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible to do what sprintf does or if the compiler cheats.  When I compile in C sprintf doesn't figure out the type size, just C++.

Comment: @Ryan, yes, it is possible, you need to look into varargs. However, it's still an incredibly bad idea since it allows you to disassociate the type specifier from the type, something c++ streams was built to prevent.

Comment: How do you do it with varargs?  Does varargs save the size info of each parameter?

Comment: @Ryan, my comment was to look into varargs, that means _you_ need to investigate it - my answer remains "please, for the love of whatever gods you believe in, don't do this" :-) No, it doesn't save size info (neither does the real `printf`), that's why it's dangerous. If your format string doesn't match your actual arguments, all bets are off.

Comment: It's the most efficient and easiest way to format strings, would just take some C++ extensions to make it type safe too.

Comment: Nvm I can make it type safe by building a class around basic types that have methods to get boxed versions of themselves

Comment: If you have solved your problem, Ryan, then you are welcome to post an answer to your question showing how you did it. (Answering your own question even earns you a badge.)

Comment: Well I ended up going a slightly different route but you can make a type safe formatting function by building functions for all the basic types that returns a Formattable type object.  Like this:  sprintf(string, "%u %d", GetObject(5), GetObject(-5));  This is still unsafe though since the number of parameters could be different.  Can't do a fully safe version in one line of code in C++.

Comment: Ryan, I think you'll find that `stringstream ss; ss << 5 << ' ' << -5;` is quite typesafe in one line of code :-)

Comment: Also: `std::string s = str( boost::format(" %d %d ") % 5 % -5 );` is quite typesafe as well [if you use boost format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/format/doc/format.html)